# JavaScriptのtry catch

Tags: javascript

Javascriptでどこでエラーが出ているのか、わからないので、try catchを実装したいと思っています。

ざっくりでいいので簡単なtry catchを教えていただけると助かります。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: とりあえずを`try { /* ここにコード全体 */ } catch (e) { console.error(e); }`でいいと思いますが、可能であれば具体的なコードを示していただけると、どこが問題なのかもあわせて指摘してもらえるかもしれません。

Comment: はい、まずはtry{}catch(e){}で入れてみます。やってることは、phpからpsqlのデータをjavasciripに渡して表示しているような感じです。具体的にコードを記載するようにします。

Comment: 私の理解では、try{}catch{}でtryの中のエラー部分をeに突っ込むことで、console.error(e)を表示させるような感じなんですかね？？

Answer (score 2):

ひとまず簡単には、

```
try {
    /* ここにコード全体 */
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

で良いと思います。つまり、コード全体において最初に出たエラーをcatchして、それをそのままコンソールに出力するということです。

また単にエラーの場所を探りたいだけで、かつブラウザ上で実行しているのでしたら、ブラウザのツール（たとえばGoogle chromeの「開発者ツール」のConsole)を使うと、出ているエラーと、そのエラーが出たファイルおよび行数が分かるはずです。

-- [rio.irikamiさん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/15182/rio-irikami)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34056/javascript%E3%81%AEtry-catch#comment33642_34056)より。